# EventHub is not returning the finished job state

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-media-services

**I am trying get the Job state but Task is not finishing as it is going to the else polling block**

Please can anyone guide me i am unablet to figure it out

This is what i hava tried

```
            #region Job Status Action

            EventProcessorClient processorClient = null;
            BlobContainerClient storageClient = null;
            MediaServicesEventProcessor mediaEventProcessor = null;
            //log.LogInformation($"Job '{jobName}' submitted.");

            try
            {
               
                Console.WriteLine("Creating a new client to process events from an Event Hub...");
                var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                var EventHubConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb://komurojusaikrishn.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<Shared Access key>";
                //var storageConnectionString = string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}",
                //   config.AccountName, config.StorageAccountKey);
                var storageConnectionString = string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<Account Name>;AccountKey=<Account key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");

                var blobContainerName = "asset-fcc961b8-cc25-4f4f-8617-9c767d865572";//"blob-01182023";//config.StorageContainerName;
                var eventHubsConnectionString = EventHubConnectionString;
                var eventHubName = "<Event Hub Name>";
                var consumerGroup = "$Default";//config.EventHubConsumerGroup;

                storageClient = new BlobContainerClient(
                    storageConnectionString,
                    blobContainerName);

                processorClient = new EventProcessorClient(
                    storageClient,
                    consumerGroup,
                    eventHubsConnectionString, eventHubName);

                AutoResetEvent jobWaitingEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

                
                IList<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

              
                Task jobTask = Task.Run(() =>
                jobWaitingEvent.WaitOne());
                tasks.Add(jobTask);

                // 30 minutes timeout.
                var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var timeout = Task.Delay(5 * 60 * 1000, cancellationSource.Token);

                tasks.Add(timeout);
                mediaEventProcessor = new MediaServicesEventProcessor(jobName, jobWaitingEvent, null);
                processorClient.ProcessEventAsync += mediaEventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync;
                processorClient.ProcessErrorAsync += mediaEventProcessor.ProcessErrorAsync;

                await processorClient.StartProcessingAsync(cancellationSource.Token);

              //**Here the condition is failing always because jobTask is not completed and** //**going to the else block**
                if (await Task.WhenAny(tasks) == jobTask)
                {
                   
                    cancellationSource.Cancel();
                   
                    job = await client.Jobs.GetAsync(config.ResourceGroup, config.AccountName, ObjReqconfig.TransformName, jobName);
                }
                else
                {

                    jobWaitingEvent.Set();
                    throw new Exception("Timeout occurred.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Warning: Failed to connect to Event Hub, please refer README for Event Hub and storage settings.");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                Console.WriteLine("Polling job status...");
                job = await JobStatusChecker.WaitForJobToFinishAsync(client, config.ResourceGroup, config.AccountName, ObjReqconfig.TransformName, jobName);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (processorClient != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Job final state received, Stopping the event processor...");
                    await processorClient.StopProcessingAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine();

                   
                    processorClient.ProcessEventAsync -= mediaEventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync;
                    processorClient.ProcessErrorAsync -= mediaEventProcessor.ProcessErrorAsync;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            //TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - startedTime;
```

**MediaServicesEventProcessor.cs  :**

```
public class MediaServicesEventProcessor
{
    private readonly AutoResetEvent jobWaitingEvent;
    private readonly string jobName;
    private readonly string liveEventName;

    public MediaServicesEventProcessor(string jobName, AutoResetEvent jobWaitingEvent, string liveEventName)
    {
        this.jobName = jobName;
        this.jobWaitingEvent = jobWaitingEvent;
        this.liveEventName = liveEventName;
    }

    public Task ProcessErrorAsync(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in the EventProcessorClient");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tOperation: { args.Operation }");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tException: { args.Exception }");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task ProcessEventsAsync(ProcessEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.HasEvent)
        {
            PrintJobEvent(args.Data);
        }

        return args.UpdateCheckpointAsync();
    }

    private void PrintJobEvent(Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventData eventData)
    {
        // data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.EventBody);
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        };
        //EventGridEvent[] egEvents
        var jsonArray = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EventGridEvent[]>(eventData.EventBody.ToString(), options);

        //foreach (Azure.Messaging.EventGrid.EventGridEvent e in jsonArray)
        foreach (EventGridEvent e in jsonArray)
        {
            var subject = e.Subject;
            var topic = e.Topic;
            var eventType = e.EventType;
            var eventTime = e.EventTime;
            string eventSourceName = Regex.Replace(subject, @"^.*/", "");


            if (eventSourceName != jobName && eventSourceName != liveEventName)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Log the time and type of event
            Console.WriteLine($"{eventTime}   EventType: {eventType}");

            switch (eventType)
            {
                // Job state change events
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobStateChange":
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobScheduled":
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobProcessing":
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobCanceling":
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobFinished":
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobCanceled":
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobErrored":
                    {
                        MediaJobStateChangeEventData jobEventData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MediaJobStateChangeEventData>(e.Data.ToString(), options);

                        Console.WriteLine($"Job state changed for JobId: {eventSourceName} PreviousState: {jobEventData.PreviousState} State: {jobEventData.State}");

                        // For final states, send a message to notify that the job has finished.
                        if (eventType == "Microsoft.Media.JobFinished" || eventType == "Microsoft.Media.JobCanceled" || eventType == "Microsoft.Media.JobErrored")
                        {
                            // Job finished, send a message.
                            if (jobWaitingEvent != null)
                            {
                                jobWaitingEvent.Set();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                // Job output state change events
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobOutputStateChange":
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobOutputScheduled":
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobOutputProcessing":
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobOutputCanceling":
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobOutputFinished":
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobOutputCanceled":
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobOutputErrored":
                    {
                        MediaJobOutputStateChangeEventData jobEventData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MediaJobOutputStateChangeEventData>(e.Data.ToString(), options);

                        Console.WriteLine($"Job output state changed for JobId: {eventSourceName} PreviousState: {jobEventData.PreviousState} " +
                            $"State: {jobEventData.Output.State} Progress: {jobEventData.Output.Progress}%");
                    }
                    break;

                // Job output progress event
                case "Microsoft.Media.JobOutputProgress":
                    {
                        MediaJobOutputProgressEventData jobEventData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MediaJobOutputProgressEventData>(e.Data.ToString(), options);

                        Console.WriteLine($"Job output progress changed for JobId: {eventSourceName} Progress: {jobEventData.Progress}%");
                    }
                    break;

                // LiveEvent Stream-level events
                // See the following documentation for updated schemas  - https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/media-services/latest/monitoring/media-services-event-schemas#live-event-types
                case "Microsoft.Media.LiveEventConnectionRejected":
                    {
                        MediaLiveEventConnectionRejectedEventData liveEventData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MediaLiveEventConnectionRejectedEventData>(e.Data.ToString(), options);
                        Console.WriteLine($"LiveEvent connection rejected. IngestUrl: {liveEventData.IngestUrl} StreamId: {liveEventData.StreamId} " +
                            $"EncoderIp: {liveEventData.EncoderIp} EncoderPort: {liveEventData.EncoderPort}");
                    }
                    break;
                case "Microsoft.Media.LiveEventEncoderConnected":
                    {
                        MediaLiveEventEncoderConnectedEventData liveEventData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MediaLiveEventEncoderConnectedEventData>(e.Data.ToString(), options);
                        Console.WriteLine($"LiveEvent encoder connected. IngestUrl: {liveEventData.IngestUrl} StreamId: {liveEventData.StreamId} " +
                            $"EncoderIp: {liveEventData.EncoderIp} EncoderPort: {liveEventData.EncoderPort}");
                    }
                    break;
                case "Microsoft.Media.LiveEventEncoderDisconnected":
                    {
                        MediaLiveEventEncoderDisconnectedEventData liveEventData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MediaLiveEventEncoderDisconnectedEventData>(e.Data.ToString(), options);
                        Console.WriteLine($"LiveEvent encoder disconnected. IngestUrl: {liveEventData.IngestUrl} StreamId: {liveEventData.StreamId} " +
                            $"EncoderIp: {liveEventData.EncoderIp} EncoderPort: {liveEventData.EncoderPort}");
                    }
                    break;

                case "Microsoft.Media.LiveEventIncomingDataChunkDropped":
                    {
                        MediaLiveEventIncomingDataChunkDroppedEventData liveEventData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MediaLiveEventIncomingDataChunkDroppedEventData>(e.Data.ToString(), options);
                        Console.WriteLine($"LiveEvent data chunk dropped. LiveEventId: {eventSourceName} ResultCode: {liveEventData.ResultCode}");
                    }
                    break;
                case "Microsoft.Media.LiveEventIncomingStreamReceived":
                    {
                        MediaLiveEventIncomingStreamReceivedEventData liveEventData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MediaLiveEventIncomingStreamReceivedEventData>(e.Data.ToString(), options);
                        Console.WriteLine($"LiveEvent incoming stream received. IngestUrl: {liveEventData.IngestUrl} EncoderIp: {liveEventData.EncoderIp} " +
                            $"EncoderPort: {liveEventData.EncoderPort}");
                    }
                    break;
                case "Microsoft.Media.LiveEventIncomingStreamsOutOfSync":
                    {
                        //MediaLiveEventIncomingStreamsOutOfSyncEventData eventData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MediaLiveEventIncomingStreamsOutOfSyncEventData>(e.Data.ToString(), options);;
                        Console.WriteLine($"LiveEvent incoming audio and video streams are out of sync. LiveEventId: {eventSourceName}");
                    }
                    break;
                case "Microsoft.Media.LiveEventIncomingVideoStreamsOutOfSync":
                    {
                        //MediaLiveEventIncomingVideoStreamsOutOfSyncEventData eventData =JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MediaLiveEventIncomingVideoStreamsOutOfSyncEventData>(e.Data.ToString(), options);;
                        Console.WriteLine($"LeveEvent incoming video streams are out of sync. LiveEventId: {eventSourceName}");
                    }
                    break;
                case "Microsoft.Media.LiveEventIngestHeartbeat":
                    {
                        MediaLiveEventIngestHeartbeatEventData liveEventData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MediaLiveEventIngestHeartbeatEventData>(e.Data.ToString(), options);
                        Console.WriteLine($"LiveEvent ingest heart beat. TrackType: {liveEventData.TrackType} State: {liveEventData.State} Healthy: {liveEventData.Healthy}");
                    }
                    break;
                case "Microsoft.Media.LiveEventTrackDiscontinuityDetected":
                    {
                        MediaLiveEventTrackDiscontinuityDetectedEventData liveEventData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MediaLiveEventTrackDiscontinuityDetectedEventData>(e.Data.ToString(), options);
                        Console.WriteLine($"LiveEvent discontinuity in the incoming track detected. LiveEventId: {eventSourceName} TrackType: {liveEventData.TrackType} " +
                            $"Discontinuity gap: {liveEventData.DiscontinuityGap}");
                    }
                    break;
                case "Microsoft.Media.LiveEventChannelArchiveHeartbeatEvent":
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"LiveEvent archive heartbeat event detected. LiveEventId: {eventSourceName}");
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Data.ToString());

                    }
                    break;


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please help me what i have missed
Additonal query :  in the above code do i need to create separate blobContainer or do i have to use the same container which i used for the inputAsset creation

Comment: Could you trim down the code to show just the relevant pieces?

Comment: Sure I have changed the above part  @PeterBons

Comment: I did not go through your code, but I noticed that you set the timeout for 5 minutes. Is it possible that the encoding job will take more than 5 minutes? Can you confirm from the Azure portal and check how much the job takes to finish encoding?

Comment: It takes probably like 1 to 2min